# How to suppress the default mod_perl error page in legacy CGI script using ModPerl::Registry

Tags: perl, cgi, mod-perl, mod-perl2, mod-perl-registry

I have a CGI script in Perl that generates HTTP error pages by itself.  I am running it under mod_perl via [ModPerl::Registry](http://p3rl.org/ModPerl::Registry), using the following Apache2 configuration:

```
Alias /perl "/var/www/perl"
<Directory "/var/www/perl">
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
    PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Everything is fine, except a little problem: when HTTP status printed in headers is different than 200 (for instance 404), Apache appends a default HTML error document to my own generated response.

Take for example the following simple CGI script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(:standard :escapeHTML -nosticky);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

use Apache2::Const qw(:http :common);

our $cgi = CGI->new();

print $cgi->header(-type=>'text/html', -charset => 'utf-8',
                   -status=> '404 Not Found');
our $mod_perl_version = $ENV{'MOD_PERL'} ? " $ENV{'MOD_PERL'}" : '';
print <<"EOF";
<html>
<head>
<title>die_error_minimal$mod_perl_version 
</head>
<body>
404 error
</body>
</html>
EOF

exit;
```

Running it with Apache configuration mentioned above results in

```html
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sun, 27 Nov 2011 13:17:59 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.54 (Fedora)
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<html>
<head>
<title>die_error_minimal mod_perl/2.0.1 
</head>
<body>
404 error
</body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /perl/die_error_minimal.cgi was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.0.54 (Fedora) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Note that replacing `exit;` in the example CGI script above with either `return Apache2::Const::OK;` or `return Apache2::Const::DONE;`, as recommended in "[How do I suppress the default apache error document in mod_perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1681030/46058)" question on SO doesn't help -- the result stays the same.

What should I fix in my Apache configuration, or what should I add to my CGI script to suppress appending error page by mod_perl / Apache to generated response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FAQ works for me  , after your CGI is done, after headers are sent, tell apache the status is ok, so it doesn't send ErrorDocument
http://search.cpan.org/~gozer/mod_perl-1.31/faq/mod_perl_faq.pod#So_how_do_I_use_mod_perl_in_conjunction_with_ErrorDocument%3F

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict; use warnings;
use CGI;

Main( @ARGV );
exit( 0 );

sub Main { 
    my404();
#~ my $r = CGI::Simple->new->_mod_perl_request;
    my $r = CGI->new->r;
    $r->status(200);
    return;
}
sub my404 {
    my $cgi = CGI->new;
    print $cgi->header(  -status => 404 );
    print "<html><title>print404 says tough noogies</title>
<body><h1>tough noogies</h1></body></html>";
}
__END__

GET http://localhost/perl/print404
User-Agent: lwp-request/6.03 libwww-perl/6.03

404 Not Found
Connection: close
Date: Sun, 27 Nov 2011 20:55:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.54 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.0.54 OpenSSL/0.9.7g PHP/4.3.11 mod_perl/2.0.1 Perl/v5.8.9
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Client-Date: Sun, 27 Nov 2011 20:55:39 GMT
Client-Peer: 127.0.0.1:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Title: print404 says tough noogies

<html><title>print404 says tough noogies</title>
<body><h1>tough noogies</h1></body></html>
```

Comment: BTW. what **Apache configuration** do you use?  Could you add it to response if it is different from mine?  TIA.

Comment: Unfortunately in some cases (read: for other people) this leads to sending page with HTTP status "200 OK" instead of correct error info.

Answer (score 3):

My version of the code, but working more stable:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI qw/:standard/ ;

my $Content_of_webpage = 'Oops. 404 error ...' ;
my $status_code = 404 ;


  if( $ENV{MOD_PERL} ) { # mod_perl ON

    my $r = CGI->new->r ;
    $r->status($status_code) ;
    $r->content_type("text/html; charset=UTF-8") ;
    $r->rflush ; # send the headers out << it is the trick :)
    $r->status(200) ;      

  }
  else { # mod_perl OFF

   my $cgi = CGI->new ;
   print $cgi->header( 

     -type    => "text/html",
     -status  => $status_code,
     -charset => 'UTF-8'

   );    

  }

 print $Content_of_webpage ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I seem to be facing the same problem: I set header status to 400 in case of an error and return JSON array to describe the actual error.

When I do:

```
print $main::cgi->header(@ret), $html;
```

With variables:

```
@ret: {'-type' => 'application/json','-charset' => 'utf-8','-status' => '400 Bad Request'}
$html: '{"errors":{"short_name":["Missing!"]}}'
```

I will end up with this:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Response: {"errors":{"short_name":["Missing!"]}<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
  <html><head>
  <title>400 Bad Request</title>
  </head><body>
  <h1>Bad Request</h1>
  <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
  </p>
  <hr>
  <address>Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
  </body></html>
```

Using the method described by faquer will in deed suppress the error document, but still returns status 200 OK, like Jakub Narębski points out.

---

BUT! I have found a workaround, where $r is a  Apache2::RequestRec, using this:
http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/coding/coding.html#Forcing_HTTP_Response_Headers_Out
(otherwise you would use $r->send_http_header(), I guess)

```
print $main::cgi->header(@ret), $html;
my $r = $main::cgi->r;
$r->rflush; # force sending headers (with headers set by CGI)
$r->status(200); # tell Apache that everything was ok, dont send error doc.
```

HTTP response:

```
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Response: {"errors":{"short_name":["Missing!"]}}
```

---

Apache config:

```
PerlModule ModPerl::PerlRun
PerlModule CGI
PerlModule Apache::DBI
PerlRequire /var/www/html/startup.pl
PerlSendHeader On
```

.htaccess:

```
<Files *.cgi>
 SetHandler  perl-script
 PerlHandler ModPerl::PerlRun
 Options ExecCGI
</Files>
```

Comment: If only I could upvote this more than once! this was driving me and my team up the walllll.