# Perl CGI "400 Bad Request" - not coming as json instead response type is html

Tags: apache, perl, cgi, mod-perl

When try to return the JSON response with status code "400 Bad Request", perl cgi always responding with text/html where as for 200, its returning JSON data correctly.

Using apache server.

Answer (score 0):

It got worked after use
Apache2::RequestUtil->request->rflush;

Thanks for the [How to suppress the default mod_perl error page in legacy CGI script using ModPerl::Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288425/how-to-suppress-the-default-mod-perl-error-page-in-legacy-cgi-script-using-modpe)